# The [calling] tag is ambiguous, what should it be used for?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Currently, there are 211 questions tagged [calling](/questions/tagged/calling), with very little rhyme or reason. It has been used for many things, including:

- Method/function calling
- Phone calls
- Web API calling

As far as I can tell, this tag means absolutely nothing, and could be BURNiNATED with no issues ([0 questions tagged just 'calling'](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/112203)), but is that the best course of action here?

It appears we have the same dilemma with the [caller](/questions/tagged/caller) tag. Let troggy burninate more!

Comment: Sure one for burnination..

Comment: That is indeed a stupid tag. Kill it on sight.

Comment: Is there a badge for removing question linked to a tag? I will do this...it will take 1-2 hours :D

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Except for an increase in editing count; no!

Comment: Burnination beginning.

Comment: It looks like the decision here was to burn it but the tag is still around. Calling Trogdor!

Comment: How about [tag:call] and [tag:calls]?

Answer (score 4):

*Tudududu!*

[image]

Comment: Now I'll never find my calling on Stack Overflow. Thanks a lot, Troggy.

Answer (score 2):

**Delete the tag.**  I don't see how the tag refers to anything specific.

*waiting for Trogdor...* `:P`